# java- storing string values- which is most efficient- linked list, array list or hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, hashmap

In a java application, I have a requirement where a user will define a string value, and then keep on appending further string values to original value...

There can be multiple different named strings defined by the user..

From hashmap, array list and linked list, which one should I use on the basis of following criteria:

(1) Most memory efficient
(2) Max possible space per single string value

Also what is the max possible size of a single string value in all 3 options (hashmap/array list/linked list) ?

Comment: A String is a String is a String.

Comment: If user is appending into a String only then why would you need a Collection. You will be fine with StringBuilder or StringBuffer.

Comment: If you need a Map (because there is some key / value relation to you Strings) how would a List work for you? If you do not have a key / value relationship, how would a Map work for you? In the choice of an ArrayList vs. LinkedList the decision is based on the amount of changes to be made to the list vs. the number of times the list will be iterated or value retrieved via an index.

Answer (score 5):

If the user is entering the string, you shouldn't need to worry.  The maximum String length is over 2 billion.

> The fastest typing speed ever, 216 words per minute,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_per_minute

This means even a fast typist will take a minute to write 1 K of letters. To write one String which is maximum length will take 1491 days, non stop. (Assuming their keyboard, computer, or the user does die in the attempt)

It is highly unlikely you need to most efficient data structure and using the simplest and most obvious choice is a better approach. (Again because users cannot type fast enough for it to ever matter)

A Kindle can store thousands of books in a device which costs less than 100 pounds. A user could write all their live and not write enough to fill up a small, cheap mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Save your time and use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) (if you need thread safety).

Answer (score 0):

You will need `ArrayList<Stringbuffer>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a text editor where the user can jump to anywhere in the string and start changing it, a gap buffer is a fairly good data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer